# RSA - Is $e = d$ a problem?

Tags: rsa, keys

I'm working on small RSA project in university.
At this moment I have done this:

1. An array of prime numbers is generated from selected range.
2. $p$ and $q$ selected randomly from this array
3. $n$ calculated
4. $\phi(n)$ calculated
5. $e$ calculated
6. $d$ calculated

What do you think about $e$ and $d$ in that case?

- $p = 29$
- $q = 53$
- $n = 1537$
- $\phi(n) = 1456$
- $e = 545$
- $d = 545$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be disastrous if an RSA key generation procedure had a sizable probability to end with $e=d$, because in that case, the public key reveals the private key, which must be secret from a security perspective.

But $e=d$ is a symptom of a larger problem lying in steps 1 and 2 of the key generation procedure: RSA can only be secure if $p$ and $q$ are selected in a way such that factoring $n$ is hard, and that means $p$ and $q$ should be large primes. The modern baseline is $n$ of $2048$ bits, that is $617$ decimal digits, not $4$ decimal digits. For this, $p$ and $q$ are chosen randomly among a sizable subset of primes of about $309$ digits. There are over about $10^{305}$ such primes, thus generating them all then picking within that is infeasible. The right procedure is to directly generate $p$ and $q$.

With $p$ and $q$ random primes this large, and a random choice of $e$ such that $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$ (or a random choice of primes $p$ and $q$ with the only dependency on $e$ that $\gcd(e,p-1)=1$ and $\gcd(e,q-1)=1$, as is common practice), it's infinitesimally improbable that $d=e$, or more generally that one or a few re-encryption(s) lead to decryption. See [these](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/80806/555) [questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3055/555) [on the](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/909/555) [cycling attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1572/555).

---

There are RSA key generation procedures in [FIPS 186-4 appendix B.3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=59). Ignore the proposed $1024$-bit key size, which is obsolete. The proposed $2048$ is the baseline, $3072$ increasingly common, extending to $4096$-bit not unreasonable. These procedures differ from those used in the question by several points including:

- Generating large primes $p$ and $q$ unpredictably in a prescribed interval $[2^{(k-1)/2},2^{k/2}]$, where $k$ is the desired bit size of $n$ (e.g. $3072$)
- Requiring odd $e$ with $2^{16}<e<2^{256}$ (the lower because that acts as a safeguard against poor choices of RSA padding, the higher for interoperability and to make some other poor choices impossible)
- Using $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ (where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)) rather than $d=e^{-1}\bmod\phi(n)$. Both are mathematically fine, but using $\lambda$ insures generating the smallest positive private exponent $d$ working for a given $(n,e)$.
- Requiring a minimum size of $d$ (much larger than $2^{256}$, which incidentally insures $d>e$), more as a safeguard against errors than out of mathematical necessity.

Comment: Increasing p and q helps to make e smaller. p - 19889; q - 11579; e - 23. But I still have big d - 214516652

Comment: See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555) for a recent history of record factorizations and convince you that RSA with $n$ not at least in the hundred digits is pointless in any project putting RSA to use. $d$ must be large enough, otherwise it can be found from $n$ and $e$ (see [Boneh and Durfee](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/lowRSAexp.html)). Practice is $d$ about as large as $n$, and $e=65537$, which is extremely small compared to $d$.

Comment: Is there any way to do 1999^2001%347 in programming?

Comment: $1999^{2001}\bmod347$ is amenable to "programming" in all common languages. In python, that can be `pow(1999,2001,347)`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EoyC/XMPQ0tJSx8jAwFDH2MRcU/P/fwA). It uses standard techniques in [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) to neither compute $1999^{2001}$ explicitly as the working `1999**2001%347` would do, nor perform $2000$ multiplications. Both would be feasible with this small example, but not with the much larger numbers in actual use of RSA.

Answer (score -1):

Although we commonly use (p-1)*(q-1) to calculate d, you can actually use [lcm(p-1, q-1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation) [least common multiple] and get smaller values for e and d that work. Now 545 squared mod 1456 = 1, so yes the calculations are correct (if a bit weird). Try a smaller value for e, and you should values that make more sense.

Comment: I do not see that this answers the part of the question about $e=d$, which indeed is a disaster from a security standpoint. And what does not make sense is choosing 2-digit $p$ and $q$ in any project putting RSA to use.